# How to Set Global Variable Values in the onStart parameter of Shiny Application

Tags: r, graphics, global-variables, shiny

I am trying to use the onStart parameter for the function shinyApp from the R package shiny to set global variables instead of using a global.R file. So, the format would be

```
shinyApp(onStart = ..., ui = ..., server = ...)
```

However, I cannot seem to be able to set global variables. For example, if I do the following:

```
shinyApp(
    onStart = function() { 
          temp1 <- 2
          temp2 <- 3
          temp3 <- 4
    },
    ui = fluidPage(
         titlePanel("test"),
         mainPanel(uiOutput("test_slider"))),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
         output$test_slider <- renderUI({
         sliderInput("test_slider",
                     "Testing",
                     min = 0,
                     max = temp1 + temp2 + temp3 + temp4,
                     value = 0

         )
      })
    }
)
```

When I do this, I get the error 'object temp1 not found'. I am not too sure how to make this work, so any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you can use <<- instead of <-

Comment: Wow that worked. Thank you! I will accept it if you post that as the answer. Also, if I wanted to modify the global variable in my server would I also just use <<-

Comment: yes, you can modify it like so too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To assign global variables you can use `<<-` 
E.g:

```
temp1 <<- 2
```